# Given the joint probability density function of the random variables $X$ and $Y$, determine $\textbf{P}(X < Y)$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, density-function

The joint probability density function of the random variables $X$ and $Y$ is given by
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-x-y} & \text{for}\,\,(x,y)\in(0,+\infty)^{2}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

(a) Determine $\textbf{P}(X < Y)$

(b) $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

**MY SOLUTION**

(a) According to the support of the given joint probability density function, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(X < Y) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{y}e^{-x-y}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-y} - e^{-2y})\mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

(b) They are independent since $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = e^{-x}e^{-y} = f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$. Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle f_{X}(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x-y}\mathrm{d}y = e^{-x}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y}\mathrm{d}y = e^{-x}\\\\
\displaystyle f_{Y}(y) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x-y}\mathrm{d}x = e^{-y}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x = e^{-y}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: Your proof seems correct to me. To prove independence, all you have to check is if the  joint probability can be represented as a product of two functions $A(x)$ and $B(y)$ which in this case is clear. Those functions are the corresponding marginal probabilities.

Comment: ^further, you can note that the two RVs are in fact iid, so $P(X < Y) = P(Y<X).$ Since they are also continuous, $P(Y=X) = 0$, and immediately the answer to (a) is $1/2$.